# How can I use the python-phonenumbers library to check the type of phone number?

Tags: python, sms, python-phonenumber

How can we use the [`python-phonenumbers`](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers) library to determine whether a particular phone number is a mobile number or landline number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `phonenumbers.phonenumberutil.number_type` to get the number type (after you have parsed the number). e.g.

```
x = phonenumbers.parse("0282784492", "AU")
phonenumbers.phonenumberutil.number_type(x)
```

So if you wanted to use `x` if it was not a fixed line number you could do:

```
if phonenumbers.phonenumberutil.number_type(x) is not phonenumbers.PhoneNumberType.FIXED_LINE:
    # Do something...
```

The possible phone number types are:

- `FIXED_LINE = 0`
- `MOBILE = 1`
- `FIXED_LINE_OR_MOBILE = 2`
- `TOLL_FREE = 3`
- `PREMIUM_RATE = 4`
- `SHARED_COST = 5`
- `VOIP = 6`
- `PERSONAL_NUMBER = 7`
- `PAGER = 8`
- `UAN = 9`
- `VOICEMAIL = 10`
- `UNKNOWN = 99`

See the full descriptions [here](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers/blob/c2fe6f480f24939ad64a53887e53bc6c27f7a9ab/python/phonenumbers/phonenumberutil.py#L439).